# Inhalt verhält sich zu „in“ wie XYZ zu „auf“

Tags: single-word-request

Es hat mich ein wenig stutzig gemacht, nachdem mir heute aufgefallen ist, dass wir scheinbar kein Wort für das Folgende haben.

Ich suche eine kürzere Art, folgenden Satz auszudrücken:

> Räume *[alles, was auf dem Tisch ist,]* in die Kiste.

Umgekehrt kann man anstelle von

> Räume *[alles, was in der Kiste ist,]* auf den Tisch.

kürzer sagen:

> Räume *den Kisteninhalt* auf den Tisch.

Eine analoge, aber vermutlich naive Formulierung wäre demnach:

> * Räume *den Tischaufhalt* in die Kiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wenn es kein Wort gibt, kannst du eins zusammenstellen:

> - Tischbelag (vgl. Brotbelag)
> - Tischbesatz

Oder die Bedeutung eines Wortes erweitern:

> das Aufgetischte
> (»auftischen« bezieht sich i. d. R. ja auf Ess- und
> Trinkbares)

Comment: Belag ist auf jedenfall eine gute Idee (+1)

Comment: Vorsicht! Solche selbsterfundenen Wörter können falsch verstanden werden. Ohne Kontext würde ich "Tischbelag" als analog zum Zahnbelag, also als Verschmutzung verstehen. Das "Aufgetischte" ist ganz klar eine Mahlzeit und nicht alles, was sich auf einem Tisch befindet.

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde nicht zweckmäßig, den zufällig gewählten Gegenstand, auf dem die Objekte sich derzeit befinden, zum Bestandteil des gesuchten Wortes zu machen, weil:

- das die Anwendung stark einschränkt
- alternativ eine Vielzahl von weiteren Begriffen benötigt würde
- *Inhalt* ebenfalls keinen solchen Hinweis gibt

Meine Vorschlag ist

> Aufladung

im Sinne von *Last, die irgendwo platziert wurde*. Meinem Empfinden nach gibt das auch den temporären Charakter der Platzierung wieder.

Comment: Wir haben die Frage etwas unterschiedlich verstanden, aber die Endung ...ladung finde ich eine gute Idee! "Tischbeladung" oder "die Beladung des Tisches" ist m.E. schon sehr nah an einem voraussetzungsfrei verständlichen Begriff.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke auch, es gibt kein Wort für die Gesamtheit der Dinge, die *auf* etwas anderem stehen oder liegen.

Man kann versuchen, sich bei ähnlichen Begriffen zu bedienen, aber zu einen ohne Erklärungen verständlichen Begriffe finde ich nicht, weil es kein wirklich passendes Grundwort gibt.

> Tischbeladung
> Tischgut
> Tisch(platten)fracht
> Tischlast

Auch der "Tischbelag" und die "Tischaufladung" fallen in diese Kategorie - nicht schlecht, wenn man weiß, was gemeint ist, aber das weiß halt niemand.

Ich finde das aber auch nicht weiter schlimm, für andere Präpositionen wie "unter" sieht es ähnlich aus, und das Gewünschte zu umschreiben ist leicht.

Answer (score -1):

> Umgekehrt kann man anstelle von

> > Räume [alles, was in der Kiste ist,] auf den Tisch.

Kann man machen, dann ist es halt ...

Also ich meine, daran scheitert die Frage, weil einerseits *räume [e]in* analog zu *einräumen* ist, wäre der Umkehrschluss *aufräumen*. Das ist sogar irgendwie sinnvoll, man vergleiche *etwas aufheben*. Doch denken Kinder im Spracherwerb noch nicht so logisch (s. Objektpermanenz), und dass sind bald die einzigen, denen man den Vorgang so detailiert erklären muss.